# Is $n+\frac {1}{2}$ in Kendall-Mann numbers and quantum harmonic oscillator related?

Tags: gr.group-theory, mp.mathematical-physics, intuition, quantum-mechanics

It is known that quantum harmonic oscillator is connected to the symmetric group of infinite order which is isomorphic to the permutation group. According to Cayley's theorem any finite group is isomorphic to a subgroup of permutations of elements of this group.

Looking at [Kendall-Mann numbers](http://oeis.org/A000140) $M(n)$: the maximal number of inversions in a permutation on $n$ letters – we can see [Kendall-Mann numbers’ property](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/46368/the-property-of-kendall-mann-numbers) $M(n)/M(n-1)=n+\frac {1}{2}$ as $n \to \infty$. The same structure is for energy level of the quantum harmonic oscillator.

How can  we explain this seemingly coincident based on mathematical approach?
What is behind Hamilton operator $H$ and it's $\frac {1}{2}$ expressed as $H=\left(N+\frac {1}{2}\right)\frac {h}{2\pi} \omega$?

Comment: the answer to your last question (whence the 1/2?) has a simple answer in terms of "zero-point  motion", "Maslov index", "WKB turning points" --- I can elaborate, but the Kendall-Mann numbers do not appear.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Thank you, Does that 'Kendall-Mann numbers do not appear' mean no relation based on math? I try to think about 1/2 in a way which could explain it & "zero-point motion" via the permuatationa & inversions of some mixing particles. Could you have a look at Ben Naim article  'On the Mixing of Diﬀusing Particles' reffered via the link please? http://mathoverflow.net/questions/164849/diffusion-equation-on-mixing-of-diffusing-particles

Comment: no relationship whatsoever, also notice that the 1/2 offset is not at all special for the harmonic oscillator, any bounded motion with two smooth turning points will give you the same offset.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Well, by the way I am trying to see where  Kendall-Mann numbers’ property and its Gaussian with known error of approximation (MO 164849) could be used. I heard that there is electron diffusion for high energized levels ( probably multiphoton processes in atoms). Can you guess something to apply the property and/or the distribution ( Gaussian for for the finite number N of mixing particles) to physics & an experiment?

Comment: 1/2 in quantum harmonic oscillator comes from the regularization of series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty 1 $

Comment: @Anixx Thank you. Could you clarify it a little more, any refernece on the regularization please?

Comment: https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/algebra-of-divergent-integrals.989043/

Comment: @Anixx How your approach would simplify the case and what would be the advantage?

Comment: Following the link you can see the formulas for quantum harmonic oscillator before and after

Comment: I read your comment at my blog post, Sorry, I can't add any info to that already provided by others here. There are a lot of connections among the Hermite and Laguerre families of polynomials associated with the quantum harmonic oscillator and a variety of combinatorial constructs so that it's plausible there is a connection.